# Разворот текста по дум осям

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Учю css, нашла макет там текст интересно от зеркален. Хочу сделать зеркально, данный текст, в css, пыталась с помощью свойства transform: scale(-1, -1), но не получилось, порядок слов в html, должен остаться таким же.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
    .en {
      position: relative;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);  
      color: #070707;
  
    }
    .table {
position: relative;
top:-10px;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);  
      color: #070707;

    }
  
    .ru {
      transform: rotate(-90deg);  
    }
  }
```

```html
                <div class="language" id="language">
                    <div class="en">ENG</div>
                    <div class="table">| </div>
                    <div class="ru">RU</div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сохранить порядок слов нужно вращать весь контейнер  `<div class="language" id="language">`

Для позиционирования блока (чтобы он вращался вокруг ***левой верхней точки***), необходимо написать для него правило CSS:

```
transform-origin:left top;
transform-box:fill-box;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
```

```css
    .table {
position: relative;
top:-10px;
color: #070707;
    }
  
    .ru {
     color:#828282;
    }
    
    .language{
     margin:2em;
     font-weight:700;
     font-size:36px;
     font-family:sans-serif;
    transform-origin:left top;
    transform-box:fill-box;
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="language" id="language">
     <span class="ru"> RU</span> | ENG
</div>
```

### UPDATE

Вариант ENG | RU

```css
.table {
position: relative;
top:-10px;
color: #070707;
    }
  
    .eng {
     color:#828282;
    }
    
    .language{
     margin:2em;
     font-weight:700;
     font-size:36px;
     font-family:sans-serif;
    transform-origin:left top;
    transform-box:fill-box;
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="language" id="language">
                    <span class="eng"> ENG</span> | RU
                </div>
```

Comment: интересно, попробую понять)

Comment: Здравствуйте, если слова будут написаны так  ENG</span> | RU можно ли добиться такого же эффекта? или мне нужно просто написать две строки в разные стороны и менять их когда нужно?

Comment: @Алина Вы хотите, чтобы в вертикальной строке шло ENG | RU ?

Comment: Шло RU | ENG, просто в  html что бы было записано ENG</span> | RU ,  изучаю css  и там по макету получается, что в мобильном они меняются местами, можно конечно создать два раза эту строку и просто подменять. https://www.figma.com/file/5D9pDuLtS042hzaoN69Kd7/Free--Landing--Page-Template?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: RU идёт в макете на первом месте, их нужно как нибудь поменять местами, без смены в html

Comment: чтобы был 1 класс, и просто менять его в css, единственное не знаю возможно ли это, наверное надо два класса отдельных

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вот подходящее решение:

```css
.language {
    display: flex;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

.en, .table, .ru {
    color: #070707;
}
```

Если вам принципиально, чтобы *"ENG"*, *"|"*, *"RU"* были блочными элементами, то нужно объявить родительский блок `.language` flex-контейнером с помощью свойства `display: flex;`

Свойство `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` задает направление текста сверху-вниз и справа-налево. Оно примечательно тем, что учитывает размеры элемента и так же меняет направление курсора при выделение текста, чего нельзя достичь при использовании `transform`